# Signalling issue in MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

I was implementing "Producer/consumer queue" from [Albahari's threading article link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) -->

In this article's **work** method below, if i add a console write like 
**Console.WriteLine("In waiting state .... 1")** 
before **_wh.WaitOne()**, then Signalling don't work and Consumer thread seems to be waiting indefinitely.

```
void Work()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      string task = null;
      lock (_locker)
        if (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
          task = _tasks.Dequeue();
          if (task == null) return;
        }
      if (task != null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Performing task: " + task);
        Thread.Sleep (1000);  // simulate work...
      }
      else
        **Console.WriteLine("In waiting state .... 1");**
        _wh.WaitOne();         // No more tasks - wait for a signal
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because without curly braces the _wh.WaitOne isn't part of the else statement. You probably want

```
      else {
        Console.WriteLine("In waiting state .... 1");
        _wh.WaitOne(); 
      }
```

Comment: Not related to the queastion, but I think it's also worth mentioning that this is one reason why you should always use curly braces even if you only have one line between them.

Comment: Thanks hawk. I shouldn't have missed it.